# What is causing this mayor gap between upper menu and main menu?

Tags: html, css

Something happened when I replaced a footer for a sticky footer, something in my code has created a mayor gab between the upper top menu and my main menu in Internet Explorer 7.

In IE8 and Firefox, everything looks normal.

[My website](http://www.friesecomputerservice.nl/)

Comment: Unwanted ?<div><a id="boven2" name="boven"></a> </div>

Comment: thank you for you comment, I have deleted this line, it didn't had any use undeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete all properties from `div#wrapsite_content` in style.css, it doesn't helps anywhere as far as I see and cause the problem, more specific `min-height:100%` (ie 7 doesn't support it).
So it reads it as `height:100%;` and give you this result.